# Android Studio 3.5 update issue

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-9

While updating `android studio 3.5` getting below error.

If i click cancel it deleting installed patch file.

Some conflict were found in the installation area.

[image: Click here to see the image]

Comment: I had a similar issue with a previous installation, I was told to install the newest version from https://developer.android.com/studio

Answer (score 0):

Delete all the files and reinstall in again.It's happen because of the cache